# Postgresql: syntax error at or near “.”

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why do I get syntax error at or near “.” ?

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.products (
    product_no SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date date,
    group_number INTEGER,
    CHECK (myschema.products >1 AND myschema.products <1001)
);

CREATE TABLE myschema.orders (
    order_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar,
    schedule integer[][]
);

CREATE TABLE myschema.tabletime (
    id SERIAL, 
    products INTEGER, 
    orders INTEGER, 
    CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT integrity CHECK (products IS NOT NULL
                                            AND orders IS NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT products_exists FOREIGN KEY(products)
                         REFERENCES myschema.products(product_no),
    CONSTRAINT orders_exists FOREIGN KEY(orders)
                         REFERENCES myschema.orders(order_id)
                         );
```

Comment: `CHECK (myschema.products > 1 AND myschema.products < 1001)` ... this does not make sense to me.  Where is there a column called `products` in your `products` table?

Comment: price integer CHECK (price > 0) ty tim!

Comment: `CHECK (product_no  >1 AND product_no  <1001)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is at the line:

```
CHECK (myschema.products >1 AND myschema.products <1001)
```

you cannot use the name of the relation inside a check, only the name of the columns. The [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html) says:

> Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row.